# How do you return duplicate values in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to return duplicate values in a list of lists. Say I create a list

```
my_list = [[5,5,4,6,5,6], [6,7,5,8,4],[2,1,3,9,8]]
```

I want to return every list with each duplicate value in that list. The expected output would be

```
[[5,6],[],[]]
```

I'm thinking I need to use a nested for loop to access each number inside that list.

```
for alist in my_list:
    for number in alist:
        pass
```

I am also thinking about using a membership statement to see if it's in there more than once, but I'm not sure  if I'm implementing that correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension works really well for this

```
my_list = [[5,5,4,6,5,6], [6,7,5,8,4],[2,1,3,9,8]]

duplicates = [list(set([value for value in sublist if sublist.count(value) > 1])) for sublist in my_list]

print(duplicates)
```

This gives an **output** of:

```
[[5, 6], [], []]
```

What's happening is we're looping through the three lists in 'my_list'. Whenever the 'count' of that value is bigger than 1 in that sublist, we're retaining it.

We're then converting to a set, which removes any duplicates (otherwise we'd still have three instances of '5', and two instances of '6', afterwards).

Converting this to a set (and then back to a list) will remove any duplicates, leaving us with only the multiple occurring values we're after.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [[5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6], [6, 7, 5, 8, 4], [2, 1, 3, 9, 8]]

result = [[k for k, v in counts.items() if v > 1] for counts in map(Counter, my_list)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 6], [], []]
```

**Explanation**

Counter creates a dictionary where the keys are the values of the each of the inner lists and the values are the counts of each element. For example:

```
Counter([5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6])
```

creates the following object:

```
Counter({5: 3, 6: 2, 4: 1})
```

then `items` returns a list of tuples, using the same example as above it will be:

```
[(4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 2)]
```

then using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) get only those values with count above 1.

Comment: Nice, but I think that needs a bit of explanation!

Comment: Yes, that does work but I am not familiar with Counter. Could you explain what that does?